# screen not re-rendering after changing state

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm  just starting with Flutter, finished the [first codelab](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/) and tried to add some simple functionality to it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      theme: new ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.deepOrange),
      home: new RandomWords(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new RandomWordsState();
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];

  final _biggerFont = new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

  final _saved = new Set<WordPair>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Startup Name Generator'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.list),
            onPressed: _pushSaved,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return new Divider();

        final index = i ~/ 2;
        if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
        }
        return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
    return new ListTile(
        title: new Text(
          pair.asPascalCase,
          style: _biggerFont,
        ),
        trailing: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
          color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (alreadySaved) {
                _saved.remove(pair);
              } else {
                _saved.add(pair);
              }
            });
          },
        ));
  }

  void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          final tiles = _saved.map(
            (pair) {
              return _buildRow(pair);

              // new ListTile(
              //   title: new Text(
              //     pair.asPascalCase,
              //     style: _biggerFont,
              //   ),
              // );
            },
          );
          final divided = ListTile
              .divideTiles(
                context: context,
                tiles: tiles,
              )
              .toList();

          return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('Saved Suggestions'),
            ),
            body: new ListView(children: divided),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the Save suggestions screen I built the same row as in the Sugestions Screen.

In the Saved Sugstions screen when you click the heart icon the element is removed from the array of saved items but the screen is not re-rendered.

what am I doing wrong here?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

**Actually your app is working perfectly fine with me :/**

---

Because you are not communicating the state change with the icon change. You are already changing state based on `alreadySaved`, notice how you managed `setState()`

```
setState(() {
              if (alreadySaved) {
                _saved.remove(pair);
              } else {
                _saved.add(pair);
              }
            });
```

In the previous block you are only removing or adding to your favourite list based on the boolean value of `alreadySaved` and you are not telling `setState` to change anything else. That is why the following does not produce a re-render even though `alreadySaved` is switching values

```
///These two lines do not know what is happening    
icon: new Icon(alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
              color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
```

So you can instead do the following

```
icon: new Icon(_whichIcon), //initialized var _whichIcon = Icons.favorite_border 
          color: _whichIconColor, //Initialized var _whichIconColor = Colors.transparent
```

And your `setState` would be:

```
setState(() {
              if (alreadySaved) {
                _saved.remove(pair);
                _whichIcon = Icons.favorite_border ;
                _whichIconColor = Colors.transparent; 
             } else {
                _saved.add(pair);
                _whichIcon = Icons.favorite ;
                _whichIconColor = Colors.red;
              }
            });
```

Or simpler you can do it like this, and keep your `icon` logic unchanged:

```
bool alreadySaved = false;

...

setState(() {
              if (_saved.contains(pair)) {
                _saved.remove(pair);
                alreadySaved = false;
              } else {
                _saved.add(pair);
                alreadySaved = true;
              }
            });
```

Comment: Hey @aziza, too bad our Timezones dont coincide =D

I've tried both of your suggestions, none worked. :(
When in the Save Screen, the Tap **is** handled, _saved is update. From what I gather is that the Suggestion Screen is rendered, not the Saved screen. :(